# Dask: writing to csv very slow after merging (python)

Tags: python, merge, dask

I have a small Pandas data frame (2000 rows, 35 columns) that I merged with a big Dask data frame (6 million rows, 550 columns). I converted the small Pandas data frame to a Dask data frame and I used the following code to merge:

```
final_df=dd.merge(left=small_df,right=big_df,how='inner',on=('var1','var2','var3'))
```

The merging operation was very fast, but it takes a while to run these codes after:

```
final_df.head()
```

or:

```
final_ddf.to_csv('file.csv',header=True,chunksize=1000,single_file = True)
```

The codes were running for more than one hour, then I stopped.

Any idea why these operations are so slow after merging?

Comment: Is this a typo `finale_df` vs `final_ddf`?

Comment: Yes, this was a typo mistake, I corrected the code (but this did not cause the code to be so slow, I actually used other names in the code that I ran).

Comment: I'm guessing that the `merge` operation does not do anything, but the `head` or `write` operation causes the computation. This should be slow, because you are potentially creating 2k*6M = 12 BILLIONS lines, with 585 columns...

Comment: I see, thanks. I will let the code run for the night and see if it finally ends.

Comment: Maybe try some optimization before the join. Can you reduce one of these two dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dask, all the computations are "lazy" meaning, no actual work will be performed.

You can use `final_df.visualize()` to see the computational tree being created in the background. Until you run a function that actually needs to return a value, nothing will be calculated (i.e., lazy).

In your case, the `merge` will be very fast and still return a dask object.
The output of `final_df.head()` will be a pandas dataframe (some computation was done, and persisted in memory to return to you as an object). This is why a lot of dask code ends with `.compute()`. The `compute` tells dask to actually return you a result (assuming it fits in memory).

Likewise with `.to_csv()`, something eneds to be calculated to write the csv file.